# How can I order in Linq Select Distinct if ordered by an Included entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I know that in Linq I have to do the `OrderBy` after doing a `Select - Distinct`, but I'm trying to order by an Included entity property that get lost after the `Select`.

For example:

```
var accounts = _context.AccountUser
                       .Include(o => o.Account)
                       .Where(o => o.UserId == userId || o.Account.OwnerId == userId)
                       .OrderByDescending(o => o.LastAccessed)
                       .Select(o => o.Account)
                       .Distinct();
```

As I'm doing the `Where` by an `or` of two different parameters, there is a good chance to obtain duplicated results.  That's why I'm using the `Distinct`.

The problem here is that after I do the `Select`, I don't have the `LastAccessed` property anymore because it doesn't belong to the selected entity.

I thing the structure of the `AccountUser` and `Account` can be inferred from the query itself.

Comment: Does putting `AsEnumerable()` before `Distinct` solve your issue?

Comment: @mjwills, yes it does.  Maybe you can write your comment as an answer so I can accept it.  Thank you!

Comment: `Enumerable.Distinct` is documented to return an unordered sequence - if it coincidentally does not re-order the sequence now, there is no guarantee that won't change in a future version of .Net.

Comment: Is the `Account.OwnerId` different from the `AccountUser.Account` relationship? Assuming `Account` has a reverse navigation property to `AccountUser` I think I would base the query on `Account`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the bi-directional navigation properties set up:

```
var accountsQuery = _context.AccountUser
  .Where(o => o.UserId == userId || o.Account.OwnerId == userId)
  .Select(o => o.Account)
  .Distinct()
  .OrderByDescending(a => a.AccountUser.LastAccessed);
```

When Selecting the Account you do not need `.Include()` Keep in mind that any related entities that you access off the Account will be lazy-loaded. I recommend using a `.Select()` to extract either a flattened view model or a view model hierarchy so that the SQL loads all needed fields rather than either eager-loading everything or tripping lazy-load calls.

Answer (score 0):

Since LINQ doesn't implement `DistinctBy` and LINQ to SQL doesn't implement `Distinct` that takes an `IEqualityComparer`, you must substiture `GroupBy`+`Select` instead:

```
var accounts = _context.AccountUser
                       .Include(o => o.Account)
                       .Where(o => o.UserId == userId || o.Account.OwnerId == userId)
                       .GroupBy(o => o.Account).Select(og => og.First())
                       .OrderByDescending(o => o.LastAccessed)
                       .Select(o => o.Account);
```